# Bit code iOS App, Size on App Store

Tags: ios, bitcode, app-thinning

I have enabled bit code in my iOS app and size has increased 3x times when archive was uploaded to iTunes. I am wondering if I the same 3x size will show on App store aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the case, yes.
But I don't think it is :(

> Sometimes the same binary with bitcode enabled would be 3x the
>   original size, sometimes the binary slicing will actually work and
>   decrease the overall binary size as it is supposed to do.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25972

I think it's safer if you don't use bitcode for now, until we know for sure that Apple fixed this. I'll try to dig deeper.